# How to get the screen position in an unlit shader in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, screen, shader, vertex

I'm writing a shader in Unity3D that isn't based on "#pragma surface surf Lambert" or any other built in lighting model. How do I get the current pixel screen position in the fragment program? I need it to be in pixels (not between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1). Here's my shader code:

```
Shader "selectedFace"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert 
            #pragma fragment frag
            float4 vert(float4 vertexPosition:POSITION):POSITION
            {
                return mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,vertexPosition);
            }
            float4 frag(void):COLOR
            {
                //GET SCREEN POSITION HERE!!!
                return float4(0.75,1.0,0.0,1.0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: What you need is a screenspace shader, then you can use the texture coordinates.

Comment: How do I make a screenspace shader?

Comment: There are plenty to find on that subject on google. This is a template for unity screen space shader, or image effect as unity calls it. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Image_Effect_Template

Comment: But I need to apply the shader to 3D geometry, not use it as post-process effect.

Comment: That is not an easy problem to solve and not how you do things normally. Maybe if you explain what you need it for, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I need it for a dot kind of pattern. Like if `screenx%2==0&&screenY%2==0`, then set the pixel to red, otherwise set the pixel to green.

Comment: If you use the pixel coordinates for that the dot patter will be still when the geometry moves but maybe that what you want. This requires two steps, first do a image effect that renders the dot pattern to a rendertexture, then supply that texture to your geometry shader. This is sometimes called deferred rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked how to get screen position of a pixel in the fragment shader.
Making changes to the OP's code for getting fragment shader to work.

```
Shader "selectedFace"
{

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert 
            #pragma fragment frag
            //for maximum portability using the UNITY_VPOS_TYPE 
            **#pragma target 3.0**

            float4 vert(float4 vertexPosition:POSITION):POSITION
            {
                return mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,vertexPosition);
            }

            //Mapping SV_Target(D3D10) to COLOR(Direct3D 9)
            **float4 frag(UNITY_VPOS_TYPE screenPos : VPOS):SV_Target**
            {
                 //screenPos.x - x position on Screen
                 //screenPos.y - y position on Screen

                 return float4(0.75,1.0,0.0,1.0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```